# Trace your runtime process as any method calling?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debugging

hmm, I feel my OP title sounds wrong, but I am not sure how to put it...

I mean something like during the runtime, whenever a button button being click, dialog prompt up, any method being called etc.  There will be some output that print out my StackTrace or something that indicates where I am in the code.

The reason being is, I just picked up a new project with very huge source code (62 projects in a solution), so pretty much I always have no idea whenever a Dialog or a View open, where the file is or a method is locate.  So I want a good way to keep track on where I am, tell me which files or at least the method that calling it.  Then I will know where to set a break point in VS.

But as I stated, the projects is pretty huge, so there is no way I can go to every Class and every method to add `Debug.WriteLine("Method XXX being called")`.

So I wonder is there any way I can make a piece of code being called whenever any method being executed?  i.e. Some event handler that will execute whenever method is being call?  Or does Visual Studio have a functionality that can help me trace where I am in the code? (i.e Button being click, the last return line is XXXX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a profiling tool.. Try "[Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)"

Comment: Oh wow, it works great in both WPF and Silverlight. And I am surprise how easy to use too! Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

A few things come to mind:

**Apsect Oriented Programming**

I've used this to weave in code at every method call to do extremely deep tracing.  I happened to use [Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).

**Intellitrace**

This is a pretty [handy tool from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx?ppud=4).  It looks like you can do [method call level logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264944.aspx#BKMK_CallsAndParameters).

Comment: Too bad I don't have Intellitrace... My VS is not Ultimate.  I am going to try Postsharp later as well. +1